# Prepare mathematica output to be parsed in Python

Tags: output-formatting, python

I have Mathematica output that I would like to parse in python so I can generate equivalent expressions. So suppose I have the following:

```
testing2 = 
 ExpandAll[
  D[(x - A)^2 + (y - B)^2 +  ( 
      v - C)^2 + (x + y - (S + v) - D)^2  - λ1*x - λ2*
     y - λ3*v - λ4*(x + y - (S + v))  , {{x, y, v}}]]
```

Then I solve the following system:

```
Solve[Thread[
  testing2 == 0 &&  -λ1*x == 0 && - λ2*y == 
    0 && -λ3*v == 0 && - λ4*(x + y - (S + v)) == 
    0], {x, y, v, x, y, 
  v, λ1, λ2, λ3, λ4}]
```

Which returns a list of possible solutions. One possible solution is the following:

```
  {x -> 0, y -> 0, 
 v -> 1/2 (C - D - S), λ1 -> -2 A - C - D - 
   S, λ2 -> -2 B - C - D - S, λ3 -> 0, λ4 -> 
  0}
```

Since there are a lot of possible solutions, it is quite difficult to code everything by hand. I was trying to have the output put the multiplication symbol in the appropriate place. If I can do this, then it will be easier to parse the output in python. So suppose Mathematica is outputing `2A`, I would like it to output `2*A`. Is this possible?

Comment: `FortranForm` might get you close to what you want. `FortranForm[a x^2 + b x + c]` gives `c + b*x + a*x**2`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since python has pretty close syntax as Fortran, converting the expression to `FortranForm` is what I usually do in this case.

```
testing2 = 
 ExpandAll[
  D[(x - A)^2 + (y - B)^2 + (v - C)^2 + (x + y - (S + v) - 
       D)^2 - λ1*x - λ2*y - λ3*
     v - λ4*(x + y - (S + v)), {{x, y, v}}]]
sols = {x, y, v, x, y, 
   v, λ1, λ2, λ3, λ4} /. 
  Solve[Thread[
    testing2 == 0 && -λ1*x == 0 && -λ2*y == 
      0 && -λ3*v == 0 && -λ4*(x + y - (S + v)) == 
      0], {x, y, v, x, y, 
    v, λ1, λ2, λ3, λ4}]
sols // FortranForm
```

This is not ideal, but a good starting point for python to work with.

If you have access to Maple. Another solution is using Maple. `CodeGeneration` is pretty handy in Maple, it can also generate function using `numpy` and `scipy`

```maple
with(MmaTranslator);
print(??); # input placeholder
e := FromMma("{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2 (A + D + S), -2 (B + D + S), -2 (C - D - S), 
  0}, {0, 0, 1/2 (C - D - S), 0, 0, 
  1/2 (C - D - S), -2 A - C - D - S, -2 B - C - D - S, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, -S, 0, 0, -S, -2 (A + C + S), -2 (B + C + S), 0, 
  2 (C - D + S)}, {0, S, 0, 0, S, 0, -2 (A - B + S), 
  0, -2 (B + C - S), -2 (B + D - S)}, {0, 1/2 (B + C + S), 
  1/2 (B + C - S), 0, 1/2 (B + C + S), 
  1/2 (B + C - S), -2 A + B - C - S, 0, 0, -B + C - 2 D + S}, {0, 
  1/2 (B + D + S), 0, 0, 1/2 (B + D + S), 0, -2 A + B - D - S, 
  0, -B - 2 C + D + S, 0}, {0, 1/3 (2 B + C + D + S), 
  1/3 (B + 2 C - D - S), 0, 1/3 (2 B + C + D + S), 
  1/3 (B + 2 C - D - S), -(2/3) (3 A - B + C + D + S), 0, 0, 0}, {S, 
  0, 0, S, 0, 0, 0, 
  2 (A - B - S), -2 (A + C - S), -2 (A + D - S)}, {1/2 (A - B + S), 
  1/2 (-A + B + S), 0, 1/2 (A - B + S), 1/2 (-A + B + S), 0, 0, 
  0, -A - B - 2 C + S, -A - B - 2 D + S}, {1/2 (A + C + S), 0, 
  1/2 (A + C - S), 1/2 (A + C + S), 0, 1/2 (A + C - S), 0, 
  A - 2 B - C - S, 0, -A + C - 2 D + S}, {1/3 (2 A - B + C + S), 
  1/3 (-A + 2 B + C + S), 1/3 (A + B + 2 C - S), 
  1/3 (2 A - B + C + S), 1/3 (-A + 2 B + C + S), 
  1/3 (A + B + 2 C - S), 0, 0, 
  0, -(2/3) (A + B - C + 3 D - S)}, {1/2 (A + D + S), 0, 0, 
  1/2 (A + D + S), 0, 0, 0, A - 2 B - D - S, -A - 2 C + D + S, 
  0}, {1/3 (2 A - B + D + S), 1/3 (-A + 2 B + D + S), 0, 
  1/3 (2 A - B + D + S), 1/3 (-A + 2 B + D + S), 0, 0, 
  0, -(2/3) (A + B + 3 C - D - S), 0}, {1/3 (2 A + C + D + S), 0, 
  1/3 (A + 2 C - D - S), 1/3 (2 A + C + D + S), 0, 
  1/3 (A + 2 C - D - S), 0, 2/3 (A - 3 B - C - D - S), 0, 
  0}, {1/4 (3 A - B + C + D + S), 1/4 (-A + 3 B + C + D + S), 
  1/4 (A + B + 3 C - D - S), 1/4 (3 A - B + C + D + S), 
  1/4 (-A + 3 B + C + D + S), 1/4 (A + B + 3 C - D - S), 0, 0, 0, 0}}");
with(CodeGeneration);
Python(e);
```

Here is an example from help of Maple

```maple
# Translate a procedure involving linear algebra.
detHilbert := proc(M, n :: posint) uses LinearAlgebra;
   return Determinant( HilbertMatrix( n ) );
end proc:
Python(detHilbert);
import numpy.linalg
import scipy.linalg

def detHilbert (M, n):
    return(numpy.linalg.det(scipy.linalg.hilbert(n)))
```

### Update: sympy method

sympy has now support translate MMA code to sympy. Since this is a pretty new method, I will demonstrate a bit here.

```python
In [1]: from sympy.parsing import mathematica

In [2]: mathematica.parse('Sin[a]^2 27 + 54 x + 36 x^2 + 8 x^3')
Out[2]: 'sin(a)**2 27+54 x+36 x**2+8 x**3'
```

Noted: `sympy` does not handle the multiplication correctly now, but I believe this will be solved in the future. The list conversion is not correct as well.

Currently, you can do something like this:

in MMA:

```
In[178]:= {Sin[a]^2 27 + 54 x + 36 x^2 + 8 x^3, ArcTan[x]} // InputForm

Out[178]//InputForm=
{54*x + 36*x^2 + 8*x^3 + 27*Sin[a]^2, ArcTan[x]}
```

Copy the output to `Python`:

```python
In [3]: mathematica.parse('54*x + 36*x^2 + 8*x^3 + 27*Sin[a]^2')
Out[3]: '54*x+36*x**2+8*x**3+27*sin(a)**2'
```

This result can be further converted to sympy object

```python
In [4]: mathematica.sympify(_)
Out[4]: 8*x**3 + 36*x**2 + 54*x + 27*sin(a)**2
```

You may also use `mathematica` function in the module to merge above two functions. But I do not suggest to use the function. Because for `parse` function, you get the parse result in any case, but `mathematica` function returns a result only the result is a valid sympy expression. Here is a example of using `mathematica` function:

```python
In [1]: from sympy.parsing import mathematica as M
In [2]: M.mathematica('4a+8b^2+Cos[9a]')
Out[2]: 4*a + 8*b**2 + cos(9*a)
```

It is very welcomed if you can improve Mathematica parser in sympy.

Comment: Another approach is Robert Jacobson's FoxySheep parser which I have put on PyPI and added a crude translator to Python/Numpy/Sympy. The code in sympy seems to work using regexps largely. This approach uses a pretty good parser, than transforms the parse tree into a Python AST and finally dumps that out as text. Although it is very crude, it can handle the 0 vs 1 origin indexing differences, and deeper parsing and translation. There is still a lot of low-hanging fruit here, but I must stop working on this for now. It could however be integrated int sympy.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a Module I prepared to convert most expressions (including lists) to Numpy. It may not be the most elegant solution, but it works pretty well. Below I also include some examples.

```
 ToPython[x_, numpyprefix_: "numpy"] := 
 Module[{expression = x, greekrule, PythonForm, 
   numpypre = numpyprefix, lp, rp, a, b},
  (*FUNCTION TO CONVERT MATHEMATICA EXPRESSION TO NUMPY;
  ----------------------------------------------------;
  INPUT ARGUMENTS;
  x: your mathematica expression, it can be numbers, literals, 
  complexes or lists;
  numpy\[LetterSpace]prefix: 
  string defining your Numpy import prefix, e.g.:
  if your used "import numpy as np", 
  your prefix should be the string "np"
  if your used "from numpy import *", 
  your prefix should be the empty string ""
  ;
  OUTPUT;
  the Numpy python-ready expression (to be copied as a string);
  !The formatted expression will be copied ot your clipboard, 
  ready to paste on Python!;
  ------------------------------------------------------;
  Not tested for every possible combination; use at your risk, 
  by Gustavo Wiederhecker*)

  If[numpyprefix == "", sep = "", 
   sep = "."];(*if no prefix is included, 
  the "." separator is not used*)
  lp = "( ";
  rp = " )";
  PythonForm[Rational[a_, b_]] := 
   PythonForm[a] <> "/" <> PythonForm[b];
  PythonForm[Complex[a_, b_]] := 
   "complex" <> lp <> PythonForm[a] <> "," <> PythonForm[b] <> rp;
  PythonForm[Times[a_, b_]] := PythonForm[a] <> " * " <> PythonForm[b];
  PythonForm[Plus[a_, b_]] := 
   lp <> PythonForm[a] <> " + " <> PythonForm[b] <> rp;
  PythonForm[h_[args__]] := 
   numpypre <> sep <> ToLowerCase[PythonForm[h]] <> lp <> 
    PythonForm[args] <> rp;
  PythonForm[Power[a_, b_]] := 
   lp <> PythonForm[a] <> rp <> "**" <> lp <> PythonForm[b] <> rp;
  PythonForm[a_ListQ] := 
   numpypre <> sep <> "array" <> 
    StringReplace[ToString[a], {"{" -> "[", "}" -> "]"}];
  PythonForm[Arg] = numpypre <> sep <> "angle";
  (*Some functions that are note defined in numpy*)

  PythonForm[Csc] := "1/" <> numpypre <> sep <> "sin";
  PythonForm[Sec] := "1/" <> numpypre <> sep <> "cos";
  PythonForm[Cot] := "1/" <> numpypre <> sep <> "tan";
  PythonForm[Csch] := "1/" <> numpypre <> sep <> "sinh";
  PythonForm[Sech] := "1/" <> numpypre <> sep <> "cosh";
  PythonForm[Coth] := "1/" <> numpypre <> sep <> "tanh";
  (*Handling arrays*)

  PythonForm[List[args__]] := 
   numpypre <> sep <> "array" <> lp <> "[" <> 
    Table[PythonForm[{args}[[ii]]] <> ",", {ii, 1, Length@{args}}] <> 
    "]" <> rp;
  (*Pi and E*)
  PythonForm[\[Pi]] = numpypre <> sep <> "pi";
  PythonForm[E] = numpypre <> sep <> "e";
  (*real numbers, engineering notation*)

  PythonForm[r_Real] := 
   Block[{a = MantissaExponent[r]}, 
    If[r >= 0, ToString[N[a[[1]], 6]] <> "e" <> ToString[a[[2]]], 
     "(" <> ToString[N[a[[1]], 6]] <> "e" <> ToString[a[[2]]] <> ")"]];
  (*Greek characters*)

  greekrule = {"\[Alpha]" -> "alpha", "\[Beta]" -> "beta", 
    "\[Gamma]" -> "gamma", "\[Delta]" -> "delta", 
    "\[CurlyEpsilon]" -> "curlyepsilon", "\[Zeta]" -> "zeta", 
    "\[Eta]" -> "eta", "\[Theta]" -> "theta", "\[Iota]" -> "iota", 
    "\[Kappa]" -> "kappa", "\[Lambda]" -> "lambda", "\[Mu]" -> "mu", 
    "\[Nu]" -> "nu", "\[Xi]" -> "xi", "\[Omicron]" -> "omicron", 
    "\[Pi]" -> "pi", "\[Rho]" -> "rho", 
    "\[FinalSigma]" -> "finalsigma", "\[Sigma]" -> "sigma", 
    "\[Tau]" -> "tau", "\[Upsilon]" -> "upsilon", 
    "\[CurlyPhi]" -> "curlyphi", "\[Chi]" -> "chi", "\[Psi]" -> "psi",
     "\[Omega]" -> "omega", "\[CapitalAlpha]" -> "Alpha", 
    "\[CapitalBeta]" -> "Beta", "\[CapitalGamma]" -> "Gamma", 
    "\[CapitalDelta]" -> "Delta", 
    "\[CapitalEpsilon]" -> "CurlyEpsilon", "\[CapitalZeta]" -> "Zeta",
     "\[CapitalEta]" -> "Eta", "\[CapitalTheta]" -> "Theta", 
    "\[CapitalIota]" -> "Iota", "\[CapitalKappa]" -> "Kappa", 
    "\[CapitalLambda]" -> "Lambda", "\[CapitalMu]" -> "Mu", 
    "\[CapitalNu]" -> "Nu", "\[CapitalXi]" -> "Xi", 
    "\[CapitalOmicron]" -> "Omicron", "\[CapitalPi]" -> "Pi", 
    "\[CapitalRho]" -> "Rho", "\[CapitalSigma]" -> "Sigma", 
    "\[CapitalTau]" -> "Tau", "\[CapitalUpsilon]" -> "Upsilon", 
    "\[CapitalPhi]" -> "CurlyPhi", "\[CapitalChi]" -> "Chi", 
    "\[CapitalPsi]" -> "Psi", "\[CapitalOmega]" -> "Omega"};
  (*Everything else*)

  PythonForm[allOther_] := 
   StringReplace[ToString[allOther, FortranForm], greekrule];
  (*Copy results to clipboard*)

  CopyToClipboard[PythonForm[expression]];
  PythonForm[expression]]
```

Here are some examples that I've tested:

```
(*Expression examples*)
ToPython[a + b]
ToPython[a*b]
ToPython[a/b]
ToPython[(a + b)/(d + e + g)]
ToPython[(a + b)^(d + e + g)]
ToPython[Exp[a + b]]
ToPython[Sin[(a + b)]/Cos[d + e]]
ToPython[Sin[(a + b)]/Tanh[d + e]]
ToPython[\[Pi] Cosh[a]]
ToPython[Log10[x]]
(*Expression with greek letters*)
ToPython[Sin[\[Alpha] + \[Beta]]]
(*Numeric examples*)
ToPython[2]
ToPython[1/3]
ToPython[1.0/3]
ToPython[2.31]
ToPython[2.31 + 5.3 I]
(*Array handling*)
ToPython[{1, 2, 3}]
ToPython[{{1, 2, 3}}]
ToPython[Cos[{1, 2, 3}]]
(*Example with numpy as np*)
ToPython[\[Pi] Cosh[a]/Sin[b], "np"]
ToPython[Exp[a + b], "np"]
ToPython[Cos[{1, 2, 3}], "np"]
(*Example with numpy as "from numpy import *"*)
ToPython[\[Pi] Cosh[
    a]/Sin[b], ""]
ToPython[Exp[a + b], ""]
ToPython[Cos[{1, 2, 3}], ""]
```

Here is the output to the code above:

```
( a + b )
a * b
a * ( b )**( -1 )
( a + b ) * ( ( d + ( e + g ) ) )**( -1 )
( ( a + b ) )**( ( d + ( e + g ) ) )
( numpy.e )**( ( a + b ) )
numpy.1/numpy.cos( ( d + e ) ) * numpy.sin( ( a + b ) )
numpy.1/numpy.tanh( ( d + e ) ) * numpy.sin( ( a + b ) )
numpy.pi * numpy.cosh( a )
( numpy.log( 10 ) )**( -1 ) * numpy.log( x )
numpy.sin( ( alpha + beta ) )
2
1/3
0.333333e0
0.231e1
complex( 0.231e1,0.53e1 )
numpy.array( [1,2,3,] )
numpy.array( [numpy.array( [1,2,3,] ),] )
numpy.array( [numpy.cos( 1 ),numpy.cos( 2 ),numpy.cos( 3 ),] )
np.pi * np.cosh( a ) * np.1/np.sin( b )
( np.e )**( ( a + b ) )
np.array( [np.cos( 1 ),np.cos( 2 ),np.cos( 3 ),] )
pi * cosh( a ) * 1/sin( b )
( e )**( ( a + b ) )
```