# Convert Mathematica output to Python code

Tags: text, output, python, input-forms

I have this Mathematica (output) vector that I'd like to convert to Python:

```
{{k[0],-o[3] k[10]-o[2] k[13]-k[19]+k[13] x[4]+k[13] x[5]+k[10] x[6]+k[10] x[7]+k[10] x[8]+k[13] x[9]+k[13] x[10]+k[10] x[11],0,0,k[13] x[1],k[13] x[1],k[10] x[1],k[10] x[1],k[24]+k[10] x[1],k[13] x[1],k[26]+k[13] x[1],k[10] x[1]},{-k[0]-k[17],0,0,0,k[3],k[5],0,0,0,0,0,0}}
```

I want the variables to stay the same, unlike `InputForm`, that converts e.g. `k[1]` to ``` StringForm["k[``]", 1] ```; plus, I want the implicit multiplications (e.g. `k[13] x[5]`) to appear with an asterisk.

I don't mind the brackets, I've found a function that solves this last problem.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I would look at some of the "Form" commands:   ?*Form   For example, CForm and FortranForm are pretty close to the python code you are looking for,

Comment: Related: [Prepare mathematica output to be parsed in Python](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85817/731)